# Where is the source code for "Generate Constructor using Fields" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm looking at building an Eclipse plugin, and would like to see how Eclipse is able to perform the "Generate Constructor using Fields" action.

All I need is a pointer to the source that does the code generation for that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog displayed is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.GenerateConstructorUsingFieldsSelectionDialog` which is called by the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.GenerateNewConstructorUsingFieldsAction` action.

A quick look at the action suggests that `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.codemanipulation.AddCustomConstructorOperation` does a lot of the work. **Note:** this is an internal class so should not be called from a plug-in.

Comment: AddCustomConstructorOperation looks like it does exactly what I want. A followup: what risks are involved in using this class from a plugin?

Comment: @Kevin: Eclipse internal classes can change their calling signature and their methods from one Eclipse release to another.

Comment: See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html for a discussion about how to tell what can be used. Eclipse will usually give a discouraged access warning when using internal classes. I did see a question on SO the other day where the internal API used by something had disappeared completely between Eclipse releases.